# How to mix Cglib and JDK Proxy in Spring 4

Tags: spring

I am new to spring AOP and currently using annotation based approach for aspect. I have a query regarding proxy strategy in spring 4. Is there any way I can force spring to create a cglib proxy for concrete classes and a jdk proxy for classes implementing interfaces in the same application context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Spring actually works. The default strategy for proxying classes implementing interfaces is using *JDK dynamic proxies*, for classes not implementing any interface, *CGLIB proxies* will be created (doesn't work for final classes / methods).

More here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-proxying

Comment: *If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. All of the interfaces implemented by the target type will be proxied. If the target object does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created.* in Spring documentation explains much that jdk is used for objects implementing interfaces and cglib for those not implementing any in the same application context.@SergiAlmar do correct me if my understanding is not correct.Thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: that's correct, you might have JDK dynamic proxies and CGLIB proxies in the same application context