# Spring boot @Scheduled fails SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-transactions

This is a similar kind of question raised in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355601/why-scheduled-annotation-doesnt-work-with-transaction-annotation-spring-boot)  again this looks to be a problem on @Schdeuled doesn't work with @Transaction. 
however, this is slightly different and might be a problem with transaction handled in my code.

I'm running a scheduler which starts every day (DailyScheduler.processDailyScheduler()) and fails with the below error

> SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003 
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute
>   query     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection: next

And I also have a controller (DailyController.processDailyJob) which exactly performs the same job but that gets succeed when I run with the same input.

I don't understand why my scheduler doesn't pass and the controller works always.

Any help on this would be much appreciated! 
Thank you!

**DailyScheduler:**

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class DailyScheduler {

    @Autowired
    DailyService dailyService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${daily.scheduler.cron}")
    public void processDailyScheduler() {

            log.info("DailyScheduler starts");
            dailyService.processDailyJob(new Date());
            log.info("DailyScheduler finishes");
    }
}
```

**DailyController:**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@ApiIgnore
public class DailyController {

    @Autowired
    DailyService dailyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/v1/daily/job/{jobDate}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> processDailyJob(@PathVariable("jobDate") String jobDate,
                                                   @RequestHeader(SIFAuthorization.AUTHORIZATION) String authorizationToken)
            throws Exception {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date targetDate =dateFormatter.parse(jobDate);

        dailyService.processDailyJob(targetDate);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Daily Job Processed.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**DailyServiceImpl:**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DailyServiceImpl implements DailyService {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceRepository userServiceRepository;

    @Override
    public Integer processDailyJob(Date targetDate) {
        userServiceRepository.findUser(targetDate);
    }

 }
```

**UserServiceRepository:**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface UserServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDailySummary, String> {

     UserDailySummary findUser(Date targetDate);
}
```

**DBConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "dbTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.org.dub.mmm"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DbProperties.class)
@Slf4j
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DbProperties dbProperties;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        PoolProperties poolProperties = new PoolProperties();
        poolProperties.setUrl(dbProperties.getJdbcUrl());
        poolProperties.setDriverClassName(dbProperties.getDriverClassName());
        poolProperties.setUsername(dbProperties.getUser());
        poolProperties.setPassword(dbProperties.getPassword());

        // override the default value
        poolProperties.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolProperties.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        poolProperties.setValidationQuery(dbProperties.getValidationQuery());

        poolProperties.setRemoveAbandoned(true);

        DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager dbTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(dbEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbEntityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = null;

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter =
                new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);

        factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSource();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.org.dub.mmm.domain"});
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean;
    }

    Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the connection to the db file?

Comment: @NiVeR I've updated the db config.

Comment: Is it possible that your work (query) takes more than 1 minute?

Comment: @NiVeR Actually when I trigger the query manually against DB it takes 6 to 9 sec and comparing the time stamp in the log I see the failure error message tails after 1 or 2 mins from the scheduler task start. And to answer your question yes the work takes more than a min time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to a the flag `removeAbandoned=true`. This property works in conjunction with another one, the `removeAbandonedTimeout`. Quoting the reference in regard of that:

> (int) Timeout in seconds before an abandoned(in use) connection can be removed. The default value is 60 (60 seconds). The value should be set to the longest running query your applications might have.

So it seems that all your `abbandoned` connections are removed after 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks very much! This tells exactly why the @scheduled fails. When i trigger the controller one it just takes max of 40 sec.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Hey, how did you fix it then. Where exactly you changed the value of this flag?