# Spring boot , transactional works with scheduling

Tags: java, spring, proxy, transactions

As I know Spring Boot generate cglib proxy by default. Moreover , if my method has two annotations that create a proxy , only one of them will work. This is my test class

```
@Service
public class Test{
 
    private final TxnAddressRepository repository;

    private final CoinRepository coinRepository;


   @Transactional
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void test() {
        final TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
        System.out.println("HERE");
        this.repository.save(new TxnAddress(coinRepository.getOne(4L), hey.append("hey").toString()));
    }

}
```

But both annotations work for this method , it scheduled each second , and **((DefaultTransactionStatus) transactionStatus).newTransaction** shows me true. (open-session-in-view is disabled)

Why does it work ? (Spring boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE)

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You told Spring to schedule this method, and you told it to make it transactional. So Spring does that. Why do you expect Spring to not do what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Because it creates a proxy object with single method called invoke , if schedule annotation does a proxy and call method invoke , how it can be transactional at the same time

Comment: First I'm not sure if it really needs to create a proxy for a scheduled method. But even if it needs to, it can just create a sceduled proxy which calls a tranactional proxy which calls the method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355601/why-scheduled-annotation-doesnt-work-with-transaction-annotation-spring-boot
It shouldn't work

Comment: OK, so maybe it was a bug 2 dyears ago which has been fixed since then. or maybe you use CGLIB proxies and the user used interface proxies.

Comment: sorry , I need more extensive answer, what was wrong two years ago and how it was fixed  ;)